File download on Headless Chrome Browser not working as expected. Unsure what the issue is
I have a Robot script that logs into a portal and downloads a report. Everything is working as expected, except that the Wait Until Created is failing. The file download should be instant, but I've also tried increasing the timeout with no luck.
At this point it's not even clear if the file is downloading. Ideally I would like to search the entire Docker container for the expected file, but I am new to the Robot Framework so not clear how I do that. Any ideas? Also, any other suggestions on how to troubleshoot?
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Library    DateTime
Library    OperatingSystem  # Required to get environment variables

*** Variables ***
${URL}              https://portal.example.com/
${USERNAME}         ${None}
${PASSWORD}         ${None}
${DOWNLOAD_DIR}     ${CURDIR}
${CSV_FILE}         ${DOWNLOAD_DIR}/sessions.csv


*** Test Cases ***
Open Browser and Navigate to Login Page
    [Documentation]    This test case logs into the portal.

    
    Log To Console      .

    # Get the username and password from environment variables
    ${USERNAME}=        Get Environment Variable    CRED_USERNAME
    ${PASSWORD}=        Get Environment Variable    CRED_PASSWORD
    
    # Configure Chrome options for headless mode and enable file downloads
    ${chrome_prefs}    Create Dictionary    download.default_directory=${DOWNLOAD_DIR}    download.prompt_for_download=False    download.directory_upgrade=True    safebrowsing.enabled=True
    ${chrome_options}  Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    headless
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    disable-gpu
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_experimental_option    prefs    ${chrome_prefs}
    
    # Open browser with custom Chrome options to enable downloads
    Open Browser    ${URL} headlesschrome options=${chrome_options}
    Maximize Browser Window

    # Wait for Login Form to load then sign-in
    Wait Until Page Contains Element        //input[@name='username']    30s
    Input Text                              //input[@name='username']    ${USERNAME}
    Input Text                              //input[@name='password']    ${PASSWORD}
    Click Button                            //button[@type='submit']

    # Wait until the Dashboard loads (indicating a successful sign-in)
    Wait Until Page Contains                Daily Averages    30s

    Log To Console      Successfully logged in

Download Usage Report
    [Documentation]     Generate reports and downloading them.

    Log To Console      .
    Log To Console      Generating Sessions report...

    Click Element                       //div[text()='Usage']
    Wait Until Page Contains Element    //span[text()='Sessions']    30s

    # Get the first day of the previous month & set FROM
    ${first_day_previous_month}=        Evaluate    (datetime.datetime.today().replace(day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).replace(day=1).strftime('%m-%d-%Y')    datetime
    Input Text                          (//input[@matinput])[1]    ${first_day_previous_month}

    # Get the last day of the previous month & set TO
    ${last_day_previous_month}=     Evaluate    (datetime.datetime.today().replace(day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%m-%d-%Y')    datetime
    Input Text                      (//input[@matinput])[2]    ${last_day_previous_month}

    # Click the "Generate Report" button
    Click Element   //button[@mattooltip='Generate report']
    
    # Wait until "No results" no longer shows on the page (i.e. when the page results load)
    Wait Until Page Does Not Contain    No results    120s

    # Click the "Download" button
    Log             Results returned from report. Downloading report to ${CSV_FILE}
    Click Button    //button[@mattooltip='Download report (*.csv)']


    # Wait for the file to be downloaded
    Wait Until Created              sessions.csv    120s

   

Exit and Close Browser
    Close Browser


Did you try to add screenshots before and after download should happen? Is the ${EXECDIR} correct?

Yes. The screenshots show the expected screens, except there is no download prompt showing (i.e. the "Save as" screen I'd expect the browser to show).

Save as screen should not appear. Browser will silently download file. Log ${EXECDIR}and ${CURDIR}. Problem could be that you are checking for file in wrong dir.

The file is most certainly not downloading. The file is not showing up in the ${EXECDIR} or${CURDIR} directories.

I had the same issue and this helped me:
https://webdriver.io/docs/best-practices/file-download/
Specifically this part:
const page = await browser.getPuppeteer();
// Initiate a CDP Session:
const cdpSession = await page.target().createCDPSession();
// Set the Download Path:
await cdpSession.send('Browser.setDownloadBehavior', { behavior: 'allow', downloadPath: downloadPath });


Hi Oscar. Thank you for your reply, but it's not clear how this relates to my question. Forgive me if I've missed something.
